# How can I print attributes/meta-data of a pandas dataframe while saving it in Excel or CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `abc` which I created as follows:

```
abc = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[2,3,4]})
```

I added some additional attributes of the dataframe as follows:

```
abc.attrs = {"Name":"John", "Country":"Nepal"}
```

I'd like to save the pandas dataframe into an Excel file in xlsx or CSV format. I can do that using `abc.to_excel("filename.xlsx")` or `abc.to_csv("filename.csv")` where `filename` is the required name of the file.
However, I am not able to print the attributes in the saved file. I'd like to save the dataframe in Excel file such that first row gives `Name` and second row gives `Country` in two columns as shown below:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `.to_excel()` and `.to_csv()` do not provide any explicit functionality to insert meta information ahead of the actual dataframe as documented for the [Excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and [CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) write functions.

Regardless, one could exploit the `header` argument to hardcode this preamble into the frame. This can be achieved, for example, with

```py
abc.to_csv("filename.csv", header=[str(k) + ',' + str(v) + '\n' for k,v in abc.attrs.items()])
```

Please note, however, that data tables store homogenous data across rows and columns. Adding meta information on top makes the data harder to read and process. Consider adding it (a) in the file name, (b) in a distinct table, or (c) dropping it altogether.

Additionally, it shall be noted that as of now (Pandas 1.4.3), the `attributes` feature is [experimental](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.attrs.html) and could change/disappear at any future version which makes any implementation brittle.

Comment: I tried it. However, the attributes overwrite the columns A and B in this case. I'd like to have the attributed in different lines above the columns.